# Return values after iterating a loop R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, data.table

I have two dataframes, with the same variables (but from another source). I want to combine the two dataframes in such a manner that if there is a value in `data`, this value is kept, and else the value from `dospert` is filled in.

The following function works:

```r
ifelse(is.na(data$DOSPERT_01),dospert$DOSPERT_01_1,data$DOSPERT_01)
```

However, as I have a large number of columns I want to do this in a loop.

To do this, I wrote the following loop:

```
out <- list() 

for (i in 1:8){
  x <-  paste("data$DOSPERT_0",i, sep="")
  y <- paste("dospert$DOSPERT_0",i, "_01", sep="")
  z <- ifelse(is.na(x),y,x)
  out <- c(out,z)
}
```

This loop prints the names of the columns (`dat$DOSPERT_030`), but not the corresponding values. How can I get the values?

The dataframes look like this:

```
str(dospert)
 $ DOSPERT_01_1             : int  NA 5 NA NA NA 3 6 7 7 7 ...
 $ DOSPERT_02_1             : int  NA 5 NA NA NA 7 6 2 7 6 ...
 $ DOSPERT_03_1             : int  NA 1 NA NA NA 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ DOSPERT_04_1             : int  NA 1 NA NA NA 5 3 4 1 4 ...
 $ DOSPERT_05_1             : int  NA 1 NA NA NA 1 3 6 1 1 ...
 $ DOSPERT_06_1             : int  NA 1 NA NA NA 1 2 6 1 1 ...
 $ DOSPERT_07_1             : int  NA 6 NA NA NA 6 5 7 6 5 ...
 $ DOSPERT_08_1             : int  NA 1 NA NA NA 1 1 3 5 1 ...
```

and

```
str(data)
 $ DOSPERT_01: int  NA NA NA 7 NA 7 NA 7 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_02: int  NA NA NA 5 NA 7 NA 7 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_03: int  NA NA NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_04: int  NA NA NA 6 NA 5 NA 1 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_05: int  NA NA NA 1 NA 5 NA 4 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_06: int  NA NA NA 1 NA 3 NA 3 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_07: int  NA NA NA 7 NA 5 NA 6 NA NA ...
 $ DOSPERT_08: int  NA NA NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data in a more consumable format:

```r
data <- structure(list(DOSPERT_02_1 = c(NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 6L), DOSPERT_03_1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), DOSPERT_04_1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L), DOSPERT_05_1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L), DOSPERT_06_1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L), DOSPERT_07_1 = c(NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L), DOSPERT_08_1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",  "10"))
dospert <- structure(list(DOSPERT_02 = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 7L, NA, 7L, NA, NA), DOSPERT_03 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA), DOSPERT_04 = c(NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, NA), DOSPERT_05 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, NA), DOSPERT_06 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA), DOSPERT_07 = c(NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA, 5L, NA, 6L, NA, NA), DOSPERT_08 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Since the names of `dospert` perfectly match (adding `_1`) the names of `data`, this is rather straight-forward:

```r
all(ncol(data) == ncol(dospert) && names(data) == paste0(names(dospert), "_1"))
# [1] TRUE
data[] <- Map(data.table::fcoalesce, data, dospert)
data
#    DOSPERT_02_1 DOSPERT_03_1 DOSPERT_04_1 DOSPERT_05_1 DOSPERT_06_1 DOSPERT_07_1 DOSPERT_08_1
# 1            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 2             5            1            1            1            1            6            1
# 3            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 4             5            1            6            1            1            7            1
# 5            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 6             7            1            5            1            1            6            1
# 7             6            1            3            3            2            5            1
# 8             2            1            4            6            6            7            3
# 9             7            2            1            1            1            6            5
# 10            6            1            4            1            1            5            1
```

You can replace `data.table::fcoalesce` with `dplyr::coalesce` if more convenient, or [write your own coalesce-like function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73661961/3358272).

If you're curious, the `data[] <- ...` is because `Map` returns a `list`, which would mean `data` would be a `list` and not a `data.frame`. While we could wrap `Map` is `data.frame` to get the same effect, using `data[] <-` replaces the *contents* of the columns but not the class of `data` itself, preserving it being a frame. The example below better shows why using `data[...] <-` may be a good idea anyway.

If the assumption of same-names and same-order is not true, then we need to be a bit more careful about which columns are compared and assigned. To demonstrate why this is true, I'll change the order of columns, omit one, and rename another, so that we have: different columns; at least one column in `data` not in `dospert`; and vice versa, at least one column in `dospert` that is not in `data`.

```r
set.seed(42)
dospert2 <- sample(dospert[,-2])
names(dospert2)[3] <- "QUUX"
dospert2
#    DOSPERT_02 DOSPERT_07 QUUX DOSPERT_06 DOSPERT_04 DOSPERT_05
# 1          NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
# 2          NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
# 3          NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
# 4           5          7    1          1          6          1
# 5          NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
# 6           7          5    1          3          5          5
# 7          NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
# 8           7          6    1          3          1          4
# 9          NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
# 10         NA         NA   NA         NA         NA         NA
```

From here, we need to find where names match names.

```r
dospert2_cols <- which(paste0(names(dospert2), "_1") %in% names(data))
data_cols <- na.omit(match(paste0(names(dospert2), "_1"), names(data)))
dospert2_cols
# [1] 1 2 4 5 6
data_cols
# [1] 1 6 5 3 4
# attr(,"na.action")
# [1] 3
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"
```

From here, it's a matter of subsetting the columns:

```r
data[data_cols] <- Map(data.table::fcoalesce, data[data_cols], dospert2[dospert2_cols])
data
#    DOSPERT_02_1 DOSPERT_03_1 DOSPERT_04_1 DOSPERT_05_1 DOSPERT_06_1 DOSPERT_07_1 DOSPERT_08_1
# 1            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 2             5            1            1            1            1            6            1
# 3            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 4             5           NA            6            1            1            7           NA
# 5            NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 6             7            1            5            1            1            6            1
# 7             6            1            3            3            2            5            1
# 8             2            1            4            6            6            7            3
# 9             7            2            1            1            1            6            5
# 10            6            1            4            1            1            5            1
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution worked for me, as `data` includes more columns (which match their other datasets). I tried to use the same code to do the same as above for the other datasets, but I keep receiving the error `Error in (function (...)  : 
  Item 2 is type integer but the first item is type logical. Please coerce before coalescing.`. To my knowledge, both items are integers (class()). Are you familiar with this error?

Comment: That is a clear issue that comes from "intelligent" read functions that infer the type: when there is insufficient variability and/or content to differentiate between numeric/logical, it tends towards the simpler (logical). One hack might be to replace `data[data_cols]` with `lapply(data[data_cols, as.numeric)` (and same for `dospert2`), though it's a hack. The "better" solution is to be explicit (to `read.table` or `fread` or whatever) about column classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `data.table`, you can make use of `fcoalesce()`, which returns that first non-missing value, and avoid the verbose loop by using `Map()`

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(x = c(1, 2, NA, 3),
                  y = c(3, NA, NA, 5))
dt2 <- data.table(k = c(10, 11, 12, 13),
                  s = c(20, 21, 22, 23))

as.data.table(Map(dt1, dt2, f = data.table::fcoalesce))
#>     x  y
#> 1:  1  3
#> 2:  2 21
#> 3: 12 22
#> 4:  3  5
```

Comment: I freely concede that you answered first, though I was in the middle of writing my answer when you submitted yours. Much faster at a more to-the-point answer!

Comment: No worries! I appreciate your comment and I am happy that I came to the same solution as you did. Wish you a pleasant day :)