# How to replace NA values iteratively and conditionally in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I need to replace NA values in the column *i* with the values contained in the *i+43* column and do such thing for all the *i* columns in the R dataframe.

Let's assume we have the following R data frame with *i* == 3 columns:

> df <- read.table(text = " ID  A1  B1  A2  B2  A3  B3  1   1   NA  2   NA  3   NA  2
> NA  1   NA  2   NA  3  3    2   NA  3   NA  4   NA  4   NA  10  NA  11  NA  12  5
> 3   NA  4   NA  5   NA  6   31  NA  32  NA  33  NA  7   NA  4   NA  5   NA  6  8
> 24  NA  25  NA  26  NA  9   0   NA  1   NA  2   NA ", header = TRUE)

I did not load the table because one loads as an image and I think it would not be useful to the reader.
By the way, I need to keep the A<sub>i</sub> values, when no NAs are present in the data frame, and to replace missing values with `B<sub>i</sub>` when `A<sub>i</sub> == NA`.

I know that, in this simple case with 3 columns (*i* == 3), it is possible to solve the problem by simply running the following lines:

```
df$A1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$A1),df$B1,df$A1)
df$A2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$A2),df$B2,df$A2)
df$C1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$C1),df$C2,df$C1)
```

Unfortunately, the real case dataframe has more than 40 columns to be replaced and I wonder about a method to do that iteratively (possibly, avoiding to implement a for loop).

Browsing on the internet and on the stack overflow I did not find anything useful or suitable.
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `df` doesn't seem right: is it supposed to be zero rows and 70 columns, or should it instead be 7 columns with some rows? Perhaps `df <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, A1 = c(1L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 31L, NA, 24L, 0L), B1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 10L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA), A2 = c(2L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 32L, NA, 25L, 1L), B2 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 11L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA), A3 = c(3L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 33L, NA, 26L, 2L), B3 = c(NA, 3L, NA, 12L, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))`?

Comment: BTW, *"would not be useful to the reader"* is not quite true: if you want us to help with actionable and _verified_ success, it really helps to have "real" data. The use of `dput(.)` (as in my previous comment) is often the best as it is unambiguous and easy to use. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on the use of `dput`, `data.frame`, and `read.table` for easy consumption. Your use of `read.table` is a good attempt but does not work properly here.

Comment: It might not be "pretty," but can you subset the dfs so that the values and the replacement have the same dimensions and map 1-to-1 and then you can left join back to the original data?

Comment: Your sample code is inconsistent: in the first two expressions, you replace for `A1` from `B1`/`A1` and for `A2` with `B2`/`A2`, but then you do `C1` (ONE) with `C2` (TWO)/`C1`. Is that a typo? Also, you have no `C#` in your sample data ... perhaps you meant `df$A3 <- ifelse(is.na(df$A3), df$B3, df$A3)`?

Comment: Thank for help and advises @r2evans. Sorry, but I'm a newbie. By the way, about the last comment, you're right, it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this just by subsetting and replacing.

```r
vars_w_miss <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
vars_to_replace <- c("B1", "B2", "B3")

df[vars_w_miss][is.na(df[vars_w_miss])] <- df[vars_to_replace][is.na(df[vars_w_miss])]
```

This finds the indices of the variables with missingness and inserts the values of the replacement variables into those indices. You need to make sure the variables are in `vars_w_miss` and `vars_to_replace` are in the correct order (i.e., correspond to each other based on index).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was really simple and helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can split by the trailing number, do a simple "coalesce" (both a SQL function as well as in both `dplyr` and `data.table`), and then rejoin.

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, A1 = c(1L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 31L, NA, 24L, 0L), B1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 10L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA), A2 = c(2L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 32L, NA, 25L, 1L), B2 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 11L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA), A3 = c(3L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 33L, NA, 26L, 2L), B3 = c(NA, 3L, NA, 12L, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

# originally used https://stackoverflow.com/a/73661961/3358272
my_coalesce <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  if (length(dots) == 0) return()
  if (length(dots) == 1) return(dots[[1]])
  out <- dots[[1]]
  for (i in seq_along(dots)[-1]) {
    if (!any(isna <- is.na(out))) break
    out[isna] <- dots[[i]][isna]
  }
  out
}

split.default(df[,-1], sub("\\D", "", names(df)[-1])) |>
  lapply(function(z) { z[[1]] <- do.call(my_coalesce, z); z; }) |>
  unname() |>
  cbind.data.frame() |>
  cbind(df[,1,drop=FALSE])
#   A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 ID
# 1  1 NA  2 NA  3 NA  1
# 2  1  1  2  2  3  3  2
# 3  2 NA  3 NA  4 NA  3
# 4 10 10 11 11 12 12  4
# 5  3 NA  4 NA  5 NA  5
# 6 31 NA 32 NA 33 NA  6
# 7  4  4  5  5  6  6  7
# 8 24 NA 25 NA 26 NA  8
# 9  0 NA  1 NA  2 NA  9
```

This does assume that within the numbered columns (e.g., A1 and B1) that they are in order of preferred filling from right-to-left. That is, A1 is always before B1, A2 before B2, etc. If for some reason the `split.default` returns sub-frames with `B#` first, then the coalesce may not do what is expected. This can be fixed with more logic in the internal function.

I defined `my_coalesce` here with the assumption that you're preferring base R. This can also be done using `dplyr::coalesce` and `data.table::fcoalesce`, in case you're already using either of those packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already use the dplyr package; anyway, I would like to ask you for which parameters the function my_coalesce (or coalesce() in case I need to use dplyr) I have to use?  is the dots list empty?

Comment: Without testing, I believe `my_coalesce` can be used exactly the same as `coalesce` (and vice-versa).